# mysqli prepared statements and user sanitation

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Am I doing this right?

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['usermail'];

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Init failed";
} else {
    $cmd = "INSERT INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW() )";
    if ($stmt->prepare($cmd)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $email );
        $stmt->execute();

        echo $stmt->affected_rows . " row(s) inserted";

        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        echo "Prepare failed";
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }
```

Here's my form:

```
<section class="loginform tmr">
    <form name="login" action="regi.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label for="username">Username: </label><br />
            <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Handle" required><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="sign_up_date" value="<?php echo $_POST['sign_up_date'] ?>">
        <label for="usermail">Email: </label><br />
            <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required><br />
        <label for="password">Password: </label><br />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "right".

Though many prepared statements examples show this approach of basically directly inserting input data into a prepared statement (which is what you are doing, just with extra step of assigning data to new variable names), I personally would never even begin the task of preparing a statement on the database if I did not previously validate ALL of the required input.  For example, your code will execute even if no POST data was passed to the script. Surely that is not desirable behavior.

At a VERY minimum, you should check `!empty()` on your POST values. I would also recommend validating the email address format as well using something like:

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usermail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (false === $email) {
    // validation failed
}
```

You may also have requirements around `username` as well (like no spaces, X number of maximum characters, etc.) that you should validate against (at a minimum, I would validate that the string length doesn't exceed the size of the field in the DB).

Comment: I see what you're saying but they can't submit the form unless the fields are input with data because i'm using the html5 required tag.

Comment: @cookinggood NEVER, EVER trust client-side validation. That sort of validation may be useful for providing a better UI experience, but it is meaningless in context of the server.

Comment: Right, I've definitely heard that before. I'll throw in some isset or empty to my post values. I've always used isset but i guess empty and isset are nearly identical?

Comment: Can you explain briefly what's going on with the filter_input function?

Comment: @cookinggood I find `empty()` to be more versatile when validating input.  It would return  true if the variable is an empty string, false, empty array, NULL, 0, or is not set.  So if you are expecting a string value of 1 or more characters, this pretty much has you covered, though you still might need to take an additional step to validate that it is indeed a string that is passed, and not an array.

Comment: @cookinggood You should familiarize yourself with PHP `filter_input()` and `filter_var()` functions, as they are VERY useful for filtering input data in a wide assortment of ways.  `filter_input()` is largely the same as `filter_var()` except that it can work directly on `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`, etc.  Here I am simply validating that `$_POST['usermail']` is a validly formatted email address.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44018/discussion-between-cooking-good-and-mike-brant)

Answer (score 1):

Capturing into intermediate variables is mostly pointless, you can just bind directly against the `$_POST` variables, but other than that, this is how you use `mysqli`. This is a little rough and rugged for production quality work, seeing things like "Bind failed" is not going to help your users one bit, but that's something that can be improved.

Two things could really improve this:

- Use an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/documentation/) to abstract your database calls and keep a lot of the low-level database stuff out of your views.
- Use a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to make your application more standardized, maintainable, and open up a huge library of community code that can seamlessly plug in.